# Using R - Find the 48 hours that have the worst delays form table nycflights13::flights

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to find the 48 hours (over the course of the whole year) that have the worst delays form table ***nycflights13::flights***.

I am not sure if I need to count the delays for every consecutive 48 hrs or count delays for 2 days. Below is my R code to count the number of delays every day. How can I modify it to give me the worst delays for 48 hours?

```
library(dplyr)

flight_delayed_48<-nycflights13::flights%>%
  group_by(origin,month,day,hour)%>%
  summarise(delays = sum(dep_delay>0, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
```

Updated code with lag:

```
library(dplyr)

flight_delayed_48<-nycflights13::flights%>%
  group_by(origin,month,day)%>%
  summarise(delays = sum(dep_delay>0, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(delays_2days = lag(sum(delays), n=2, order_by = day))
```

---

Updated Code and results:

```
flight_48<-nycflights13::flights%>% 
  mutate( time_hr = as.POSIXct(time_hour, format ="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))%>%
  group_by(origin, time_hr)%>%
  summarise(delay = sum(dep_delay>0, na.rm = T))
  #### mutate(delay_5h = delay + lead(delay, n=5, order_by=time_hr))
```

Above code summarises based on delays and creates the following table with columns time_hr and delay. I want to add another column to calculate the sum of delays for every next 5 hrs. Using excel I have generated the data for **delay_5h** but How can I do the same with R. I have tried using lead function with n=5 and order_by = time_hr but cannot get the same results.

*See last commented line of above code for my attempt*

```
time_hr       delay delay_5h
1/1/13 5:00     01   25
1/1/13 6:00     06   32
1/1/13 7:00     04   28
1/1/13 8:00     07   34
1/1/13 9:00     07   45
1/1/13 10:00    08   51
1/1/13 11:00    02   58
1/1/13 12:00    10   75
1/1/13 13:00    18   86
1/1/13 14:00    13   76
1/1/13 15:00    15   79
1/1/13 16:00    19   75
1/1/13 17:00    21   58
1/1/13 18:00    08   40
1/1/13 19:00    16   34
1/1/13 20:00    11   38
1/1/13 21:00    02   27
1/1/13 22:00    03   25
1/2/13 05:00    02   22
1/2/13 06:00    20   20
```

Comment: You might consider the `lag` function, and how that might get you what you want.

Comment: So if I want to compare delays for every 2 days or 48 hrs (e.g. Jan-1-2, Jan-2-3, Jan-3-4) then I would use lag(delays, n=2, order_by=day).  But it's still not working as desired. See updated code

Comment: A two day period simply looks at any given day and it's pervious day. Your first `summarise` gives you the number of days for any given day. So we just need to add that to the previous day's delays, which can be done with lag. Just add a `mutate(delay_2days = delays + lag(delays))` to your pipeline.

Comment: So the result does not make any sense when cross-referenced with weather data. There should be a bad weather causing maximum delays during the resulted 48 hrs.

Comment: Added updated Code and results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If just looking for the 2 days in which most delays happened, could use either lead() or lag() to find the 2 day period (3-4 July 2013).

```
flights %>% 
  select(year,month,day,dep_delay) %>% 
  group_by(year,month,day) %>% 
  summarise(sum_delay = sum(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(back = sum_delay + lag(sum_delay, 1), forward = sum_delay + 
  lead(sum_delay, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(forward))
```

But this doesn't cover if you are looking for a rolling 48 hour period across days.